# Sum of 1D vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

I understand the definition of a vector space, i.e., roughly, a set V of vectors with axioms defining the internal and external operations defined over a field F, typically the real numbers (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space)

I have a problem with the 1D case, for example:

say we have 2 subspaces of the vector space W= $\mathbb{R}^2$ : let it be 2 lines, the U= "the x axis" and the V="the y axis". It seems that the sum of thoses 2 subspaces is actually the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ i.e. U+V=W.

But by the definition of the sum of vector spaces:
$U+V =  \{\textbf{u}+\textbf{v} | \textbf{u}\in U, \textbf{v}\in V \}$
(cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace)

I understand that this $\textbf{u}+\textbf{v}$ can be understood as a linear combination rather than just a sum, althogh it seems to reduce to a simple sum (i.e. the sum of two real numbers u+v=w, w scalar !) in the above case if we sum "x axis" + "y axis" since the are both = $\mathbb{R}$, however of course we know that one is the "vertical" line and the other the horizontal, i.e. I dont see how to include the notion of vertical and horizontal without referring to 2D vectors and not just real numbers.

So we would rather make more sense of an element of u of U was described as $(\textbf{u},0)$ and an element of V as $(0,\textbf{v})$ but the problem here is that $\textbf{u},0)$ and $(0,\textbf{v})$ are in fact 2D vectors !

Therefore I cannot see, formally how you would define the addtions of the "x axis" vector subspace with the "y axis" vector subspace in order to produce the $\mathbb{R}^2$ vector space ?

Comment: Yes, $(u,0)$ and $(0,v)$ are 2D vectors, as they are vectors in a two-dimensional space ($\mathbb{R}^2$). However, if you were to *only* consider $U$, you'd only need one coordinate to describe a vector in $u$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, because this is a very fundamental question. But you see my problem is: how to comply with the vector space addition U+V? how can i sum 2 scalars $u\in U$ and $ v \in V$ to produce the plane R^2 !? Could you try to demystify this?

Comment: the definition of the sum of vector spaces does not include this notion

Comment: Well, the problem is that they are not scalars - not really. The moment you embedded $U$ and $V$ in a higher-dimensional space, they became two-D vectors. Again, if you were *only* considering $U$, not as a subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, you could reasonably consider its elements scalars, as $U$ is the real axis (although it is still more correct to call them vectors).

Comment: Hum, thanks, very interesting. I think i see what you mean. It is because we consider U and V as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$  that elements of U and V became implicitey 2 D vectors with one of their componets = 0 , yes ?

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, I would like you to write a formal answer, so I can upvote it (if you want). Also, I was wondering how you would "formally" write that U is "the x axis" and V is "the y axis" , I was thinking of using the line equations "y=0" and "x=0" to define it but that seems a bit clumsy. Otherwise, maybe i could write $U = \{ (u,0) | u \in \mathbb{R})$ and $V = \{ (0,v) | v \in \mathbb{R})$ , and so $U+V=\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the problem is stated, $U$ and $V$ are derived from a two-dimensional space, and therefore contain two-dimensional vectors. Adding them back together gives back the plane, but that is where you started from, so you haven't essentially constructed anything new this way.

It is however also possible to construct a two-dimensional space, starting from two identical real axes. Call those axes $X$ and $Y$.

The **[direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum)** of two vector spaces is a concept similar to the sum of subspaces (but definitely not the same!).

Let $X$, $Y$ be two vector spaces with additions $+_x$, $+_y$. Then their direct sum is defined as the vector space

$$ X \oplus Y = \{ (x, y) | x \in X, y \in Y \}$$

with addition defined as $(x,y) +_s (u,w) := (x +_x u, y +_y w)$, and scalar multiplication defined as $ r \cdot (x,y) = (r \cdot x, r \cdot y)$.

Adding together two real axes this way yields a vector space structure which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Contrary to the vector **subspace** sum, this is an essentially new object. In fact, it's a formal way to define the cartesian plane.

Comment: Great answer thanks! I see clearly the difference and the need for the direct sum. I guess a detail, but I like details, is to specify that u and v are members of $\mathbb{R}$ of course in your example, or more generally the field on which the vector spaces X and Y are defined, yes?

Comment: $x,u \in X \cong \mathbb{R}$, $y, w \in Y \cong \mathbb{R}$, $r \in \mathbb{R}$. $u$ and $w$ are not members of the field (or they would be scalars); they're vectors in their respective vector spaces. (It's easy to confuse the field with the vector space as they are basically the same object in case of the real line)

Comment: oh yes i see. Thanks. One more question w.r.t my original question: is it correct to write "formally " $U = \{ u=(r,0) | r \in \mathbb{R})$ and $V = \{ v=(0,r) | r \in \mathbb{R})$ and $U+V=\{u+v |u\in U, v\in V \} =\mathbb{R}^2$  ?

Comment: just to be really nicely formal ?

Comment: In this particular case, yes, that works :) Note that one could also for example define $W$ as $W = \{ w = (t,t) | t \in \mathbb{R} \}$, where $U + W$ would still be equal to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: great, thanks !

Comment: maybe one more comment (if you don't mind), just that when we say this vector space is "equal to $\mathbb{R}^2$ " for example, we are really making an abuse of language and "absolutely formally" we would say "is equal to $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the relevant operations abiding the axioms ...etc" ? '^^

Comment: In case of the direct sum of two vector spaces, your interpretation would be more precise (you'd need to specify a vector space isomorphism which carries over the elements and operations). However, in case of the sum of vector subspaces, it is actual equality. There are unambiguously only one kind of addition and scalar multiplication when we are working with subspaces of a vector space $V$, i.e. those of $V$ itself.

Comment: oh ok, thanks again.